# Find $\theta$ in $\frac{\sin(45º+\theta)}{850}$=$\frac{\sin 30º}{433}$

Tags: trigonometry

Find $\theta$ in the equation
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\sin (45º+\theta)}{850}=\frac{\sin 30º}{433}.
\end{equation*}
I know how to use the sum and difference but i still can't get the value of theta. Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(45+\theta)=\frac{425}{433}$
$\rightarrow45+\theta=\arcsin(\frac{425}{433})\text{ or }180-\arcsin(\frac{425}{433})+n.360,n\in \Bbb Z$

Answer (score 0):

Use both sin of sum and product of sine and cosine rules.

Comment: $sin45cos\theta+cos45sin\theta$=0.98 I'm lost from here

Comment: What do you mean by "product of sine and cosine rule(s)"?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: First of all, write $30º=\pi/6$, $45º=\pi/4$. Then,
$$
\frac{\sin(\pi/4+\theta)}{850}=\frac{\sin \pi/6}{433}\Leftrightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}+\theta=\arcsin\frac{850\sin \pi/6}{433}.
$$
After this you will have to know how to deal with the $\arcsin$ function, meaning that there will be infinite solutions and you need to know how to obtain them from the last equation.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin(30^{\circ})=\frac{1}{2}$, we have

$$\sin(45^{\circ}+\theta)=\frac{850}{866}.$$
The exact solution is $$\theta=\arcsin\left(\frac{850}{866}\right)-45^{\circ}\approx 33.97^{\circ}.$$

Of course, we could have taken into account that there are infinitely many other solutions of this equation because of the periodicity of the $\sin(x)$ function...